# Solve for $x$ in $x\ln(2-x)\ge 2x$

Tags: calculus

$x\ln(2-x)\ge 2x$

I did:
$$x\ln(2-x)\ge 2x \Longleftrightarrow \ln((2-x)^x) \ge 2x \Longleftrightarrow e^{2x}\ge (2-x)^x \Longleftrightarrow \text{???}$$

What do I do next? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Easier is to divide by $x$, If $x$ is positive, we get $\ln(2-x)\ge 2$, if $x$ is negative, we get $\ln(2-x)\le 2$. Finally, $x=0$ satisfies the inequality, hence $x=0$ is an additional solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply dividing both sides by $x$ is not valid unless $x>0$, so you need to check separately whether $x=0$ is a solution. And it is. But if $x<0$, then you need to reverse the direction of the inequality when you divide both sides by $x$.

Note that $\ln((2-x)^x) = x\ln(2-x).$

So where you have $\ln((2-x)^x) \ge 2x,$ you can write $x\ln(2-x)\ge 2x$ and then divide both sides by $x$ again, getting $\ln(2-x)\ge2$ if $x>0$.  From that you get $2-x \ge e^2,$ and finally $x\le e^2-2.$

Also, notice that with your more complicated version that says $(2-x)^x \ge e^{2x},$ you can raise both sides to the power $1/x$, getting $2-x \ge e^2,$ and then solve that for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

for $x=0$ we have $$0\geq 0$$ which is true. For $x>0$ we have to solve $\ln(2-x)\geq 2$ and for $x<0$ we have to solve $\ln(2-x)\le 2$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality only makes sense for $x<2$. You have to find where
$$
x(\ln(2-x)-2)\ge0
$$
which happens when
$$
\begin{cases}
x<2\\[4px]
x\ge0 \\[4px]
\ln(2-x)-2\ge0
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
x<2 \\[4px]
x\le0 \\[4px]
\ln(2-x)-2\le0
\end{cases}
$$
This becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
0\le x<2 \\[4px]
2-x\ge e^2
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
x\le 0 \\[4px]
2-x<e^2
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider the domains of both sides. The domain of $2x$ is $\mathbb{R}$, while the domain of $x \ln(2-x)$ is $x<2$. This is easy to see because the unextended logarithm is only defined for $[0,\infty) \setminus  0^+$.

Then solution 1: $x = 0$

Then following where you were:

$x\ln(x) \ge 2x$

$\exp(\ln(2-x)) = 2-x \ge \exp(2)$

$x \le 2 - \exp(2) \approx -5.38...$

So the solution is $x=0$ and $x < 2-\exp(2)$